# WCF callback is not happening in client

Tags: wcf

I tried to implement WCF duplex service for my test automation. call is happening fine to server but it is not calling back to client method. I have already gone through other blogs and stacoverflow also. using Isoneway property as true, set Concurrancy mode as reentrant and usesynchronizationcontext as false also. previously it was working fine. i don't know what is causing this issue.
In this service contract, callback is added

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(ICollaborationServiceCallBack),SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface ICollaborationInfrastructureService
    {
```

In test , initializing the proxy

```
[TestFixture]
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant,IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
public class SAF_TestCollaboration : TestFixtureBase, ICollaborationInfrastructureServiceCallback
{
    private SfdTestSteps steps = null;
    private CollaborationInfrastructureServiceClient client = null;  
    private SfdTask task = null;
    protected override void TestFixtureSetupBegin()
    {
        base.TestFixtureSetupBegin();
        steps = new SfdTestSteps();
        task = new SfdTask();
        PrepareEnvironment();
        client = new CollaborationInfrastructureServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this));
    }

    public void Login(string username,string password)
    {
        TestMonitor.Do("xyz","xyz", "xyz",
            () =>
            {
                xyzzzzz.....
                OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICollaborationServiceCallBack>().DoLoginIn("xyz", "xyz");
            });
    }
```

Method is implemented in test side...

```
    public void DoLoginIn(string username, string password)
    {
        steps.Login.UserName = username;
        steps.Login.Password = password;
        steps.Login.DoLogin();
    }
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Show us the code where you are trying to call back to the client.

Comment: No, put this in the question, not a comment

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look now...

Comment: Is `TestMonitor.Do` running the delegate on a different thread?

Comment: yes, action delegate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `OperationContext.Current` is bound to the thread. If you switch to a different thread `OperationContext.Current` would be null.

Try this:

```
   public void Login(string username,string password)
    {
        var callbackChannel = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICollaborationServiceCallBack>();
        TestMonitor.Do("xyz","xyz", "xyz",
            () =>
            {
                xyzzzzz.....
                callbackChannel.DoLoginIn("xyz", "xyz");
            });
    }
```

Comment: @Varun Tiwari - You're welcome. Don't forget to press the tick next to my answer.

Comment: another problem is, i am calling this TestMonitor.Do(...) in several Apis, so every where function will be called through Action delegate, so still problem remain. i wanted to use same code base because there will be huge changes if i have to rectify this. please suggest me how to resolve this issue. for example, above you can see one level of TestMonitor.Do(...) call, here inside this, some more Apis will be called which are again using TestMonitor.Do(...).